# Ruby Windows - Eventmachine gem got installed, but throws error when executing EM.run

Tags: ruby, windows, encryption, rubygems, eventmachine

Sir, I follow the link https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki/Building-EventMachine-with-SSL-on-Windows
to install eventmachine gem in my windows system.
The gem got successfully installed.
But, I am getting this following error, when I used the following piece of code to connect to websocket and tried to fetch some data.

```
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'json'

EM.run {
ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new('wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3')

ws.on :open do |event|
    p [:open]
    ws.send(JSON.generate({ticks: 'frxUSDJPY'}))
end

ws.on :message do |event|
    p [:message, event.data]
end
}
```

Please help.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what(): Encryption not available on this event-machine

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: Hi.  Did you get this solved?  I am about to try the same thing and any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: No, it never solved. Neither have I got help.